# android: what's the error？

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I got [this warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XRzQ.png) from console when running my application on my phone. And my phone haven't any response.

> No Launcher activity found! [2016-03-11 14:44:59 - ActivityTest] The
>   launch will only sync the application package on the device!

Comment: You are missing declare the main activity in your Manifest.xml.

Comment: Why don't you use Android Studio?

Comment: You either don't have an Activity (you need at least one in any apk), don't have any set with the intent filter to be in the launcher, or you forgot to add it to the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Check this -

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You should set action main is caps 
i.e `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think your error comes because you declare this row in your Manifest wrong

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />`

Your Manifest must be some like this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstActivity"
            android:label="This is FirstActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> <-- MAIN with upper case
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

This two lines in your Manifest  always must look exactly like that.They are not classes in your app.They are actions that are happening.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```